# Visual Studio error in C, unhandled exception at 0xfefefefe

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, c11, tr24731

I am learning how to write C in Visual Studio, and here is my code,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char me[20]; 

    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf_s("%s", me);
    printf("darn glad to meet you, %s!\n", me);

    return(0);
}
```

Now, after typing all that in I get an error popping up "Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project14.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003)"

Answer (score 3):

You're using `scanf_s()` wrong. The way [described in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) is `scanf_s("%s", me, sizeof me);`

Also you really should check the return value of the function

```
if (scanf_s("%s", me, (unsigned)sizeof me) != 1) /* error */;
```

Also note that the MSDN description and the [C11 Standard description](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2) only have minor differences except that MSDN fails to inform you the function is optional for Standard compliant implementations. If you intend to run your code in other than Windows, you may want to add checks for the existence of the function or use some other way to get user input.

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
// use Annex K functions at will
#else
// do not use Annex K functions
#endif
```

Comment: MSVC note : [The size parameter is of type unsigned, not size_t.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), (but standard use `size_t`)